# Do some secrets require going back to previous mission?

Tags: doom-2016

I'm having a hard time getting some of these secrets on my first playthrough.

Are all secrets accessable with abilities/equipment you have the first time playing through the level, or do some of them require something you aquire at a later mission?

No spesifics, please. Not without putting them in spoilers, at least.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Now that I've gotten all the secrets I can finally answer this question.

In principal **no**. You do not need to revisit missions to get all the secrets. You just need keen eyes as you go through the levels. Most secrets require just some platforming to get to, but some also require hitting certain switches or pulling levers and these tend to be hidden.

**But!**

The later missions start to have numerous *points of no return* that do prevent you from going back to earlier parts of the map. These can prevent you from getting to some of the secrets you missed earlier.

> Also, the *double jump* you get in the 5th mission, the Argent Tower, makes traversing the earlier maps much less of a pain, so it's easier to get the secrets you missed.

Comment: You can always go back to play previous missions. Do you mean sometimes you can't backtrack within the mission and so must play it again?

Comment: @Dallium I have no idea what I was thinking when I wrote that. That's exactly what I inteded to write. Fixed now.